# Get all instance methods of a CoffeeScript object

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a CoffeeScript object and I want to get all of its instance methods.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

You can get all of the instance methods as they are now using the following CoffeeScript code:

```
keys = (k for k, v of obj when typeof v is 'function')
```

@thejh's solution will give you more than just functions and doesn't work in all JS platforms, but is otherwise correct. Also note that a CoffeeScript object is a JavaScript object -- there's no distinction, really.

Answer (score 2):

```
instanceMethods = (v for k, v of object when typeof v is "function")
```

[See this](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Foo%0A%0A%20%20m%3a%20-%3E%201%0A%0Aob%20=%20new%20Foo%0A%0A%0AinstanceMethods%20=%20%28v%20for%20k,%20v%20of%20ob%20when%20typeof%20v%20is%20%22function%22%29%0A%0Aconsole.log%20instanceMethods%0A)

Comment: Great minds think (almost) alike ;)  Also, this isn't quite what you want for two reasons: (1) you have `if` when you you mean `when`, which will result in a syntax error (unless `v` happens to be defined), (2) using `own` here will cause anything not defined explicitly on the object itself won't show up.